# What is difference between Work Manager vs Reactive Extensions (Rxjava) ? what should i use or when ?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

> Recently I Learned About Work Manager  now i wanted to clarify when i need to Use Reactive Extensions or Work Manager .

Answer (score 2):

these are 2 different concepts in android

basically, Work Manager came with Android Jetpack handles background operations(i.e Services) check this out [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)

RxJava is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences. check this out [doc](http://reactivex.io/documentation)

Answer (score 2):

If your source code is used in only Android then go for work manager. It is Android predefined library. It will update as per Android updates. It have greater compatibility in Android.

If your source code is used in Java, then go for Reactive x. Then it is possible to use same code using Reactive x. If you want to handle Android specific (activity life cycles, etc) then go for work manager.